# Как не дать пользователю повторно загрузить данные в БД из Excel файла

Tags: веб-программирование, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, backend

такая ситуация.
У меня есть сервис, куда входит пользователь и импортирует Excel файл, содержащий таблицу с данными, в которой 40-100 строк. Потом идет автоматический парсинг и построчный insert данных. Как я могу сделать проверку на "дурака" и защитить базу от повторного импорта файла? Например, если пользователь случайно/специально загрузит файл ещё раз. В БД на данный момент 2кк+ строк.
Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, проверка на дубликаты сильно зависит от структуры этого файла и структуры базы. Так вот абстрактно сложно сказать.

Comment: У меня есть некоторые идеи, однако мне они кажутся в некотором роде костылями, т.к. назвать их универсальными я не могу. Надеялся, что мне смогут подсказать паттерн для таких задач.

Comment: Ну, стандартный паттерн - это констрейнты на уникальность записей в самой БД. Но без знания структур ваших данных это всё пустые рассуждения.

Comment: Посчитайте какой-нибудь хэш (например, md5sum) от вашего файла и заносите его в базу. Перед каждым занесением данных из файла проверяйте, что такого хэша в ней еще нет

Comment: Это весьма хорошая идея.

Comment: у меня идёт вставка как есть, вставляю пакетом по 500К строк за день, в конце проверка всей таблицы на дубли с последующим удалением, если есть. В таблице 50КК строк, работает быстро без хэшей и прочих усложнений.

Comment: а ещё можно PK на табличку накинуть и вставлять построчно в try/catch

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от используемой СУБД, но универсальное решение - просто в коде перед вставкой проверять есть ли уже запись в базе данных, поискав ее по ключевым полям.
Если это  SQL server  попробуйте так, выбрав набор полей которые уникальны для ваешго случая:

```
BEGIN
   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM EmailsRecebidos 
                   WHERE Name = @_NAME
                   AND Email = @_EMAIL
                   AND Surname = @_SURNAME)
   BEGIN
       INSERT INTO Emails (Name, Email, Surname)
       VALUES (@_NAME, @_EMAIL, @_SURNAME)
   END
END
```

Comment: Я немного ошибся. В БД у меня 2.285.759 строк. Делать поиск по всем полям, я думаю, не стоит. А СУБД у меня SQL Server

Comment: Добавила ответ для SQL Server,  но в целом тоже будет поиск по всей бд. Все поля вам не надо перебирать - какой то набор полей - уникален, по нему и ищите

Comment: Вы говорите верно, но, к сожалению, он мне не поможет.
Моя база содержит отчет о записи к врачу, там могут быть дубликаты, если сравнивать каждую строку. Другое дело, когда повторно импортируется файл. Надеюсь, вы меня поняли.
В моем случае поможет хэш сумма.

Comment: Ну если не бывает случая что пользователь поправил файл и загружает снова - то да